# Getting errors with trying to create a CRUD Web Service

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

Hey guys, here are the errors I'm getting:

```
Value of type 'Integer' cannot be converted to 'music.MusicDataTable'. 
//happens at return deleteSong(...)
Value of type 'Integer' cannot be converted to 'music.MusicDataTable'.
//happens at return insertSong(...)
```

And this is the code, coming from the web service's vb page, where I'm getting the error:

```
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols

<WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Public Class getMusicList
     Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function GetMusic() As music.MusicDataTable
        Dim music As New musicTableAdapters.MusicTableAdapter
        Return music.GetMusic
    End Function

    Public Function deleteSong(ByVal song_title As String) As music.MusicDataTable
        Dim music As New musicTableAdapters.MusicTableAdapter
        Return music.deleteSong(song_title)
    End Function

    Public Function insertSong(ByVal song_album As String, ByVal song_artist As String, ByVal song_file As String, ByVal song_format As String, ByVal song_size As String, ByVal song_time As String, ByVal song_title As String, ByVal song_track As Integer, ByVal song_year As Integer) As music.MusicDataTable
        Dim music As New musicTableAdapters.MusicTableAdapter
        Return music.insertSong(song_album, song_artist, song_file, song_format, song_size, song_time, song_title, song_track, song_year)
    End Function


End Class
```

MusicDataTable comes from a dataset called music.

The GetMusic() works because I'm not passing it anything. I'm not sure why insertSong and deleteSong aren't working. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apparently `music.deleteSong` and `music.insertSong` return `integer`. you should change the return type of `deleteSong` and `insertSong` to integer to match them.